# How to optimize clustered index rebuild?

Tags: sql-server-2012, clustered-index

I need to rebuild the clustered index of the table that has more then 1.6 millions rows, more then 20 non-clustered indexes and 80 columns in order to reclaim space after two `NVARCHAR(MAX)` columns were deleted.

I have try using the following command:

```
ALTER INDEX [PK_A] ON [dbo].[B] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80)
GO
```

and using `DBCC CLEANTABLE` command.

In both cases it takes more then 19 hours. Is there a way to optimize the clustered index rebuild operation?

Comment: Are you saying your main purpose of rebuilding index is to reclaim space not reduce fragmentation ? Its not guaranteed you can reclaim space I am not sure whether it will do it

Comment: Yes, that is the main purpose. It is working. For now, I am testing this on local databases, and I want to reduce the execution time before doing this on produciton.

Comment: You could consider rebuilding index by index instead of all at once. (Or dropping a lot of those 20 indexes and re-creating them one by one.) Are 20 non-clustered indexes really necessary? While that is well below the enforced limit, it seems excessive to me. Also I assume you have chosen to not sort in tempdb for a reason, and to perform the rebuild offline as well?

Comment: It's very old design. I have reduced the indexes in fact(originally over 30). Is `PARTITION = ALL` option rebuilding all of them? If I rebuild only the clustered index aren't the non clustered indexes updated only? I can try this - disable or drop the non-clustered indexes, rebuild the clustered index and then recreated the non-clustered indexes.

Comment: @gotqn sorry, I didn't look closely enough at the actual statement, I saw `ALL` and assumed you were rebuilding all indexes. In any case, my question is still valid - just because it's an old design does not mean all those 20 indexes are still being used in today's workloads.

Comment: It is one of the main tables - used in a lot of places (both SQL and directly in the application). I am constantly checking the usage of the indexes and removed some of them. Some of them are updated daily, but used only for hundred of times each month - I am still not able to track where they are used (maybe some reporting service report) and to determine how critical are for the performance. You sound like it is a big issue that should be fixed ASAP? Do you think the delay is caused by them - I can check this tomorrow.

Comment: Indexes can be a much of problem if your system one receiving lots of DML or large data insert is done on table. Extra indexes means extra unnecessary I/O. For reporting purpose they "might be Ok" but again unnecessary index only adds overhead